# How to convert from permutation to combination in Java?

Tags: java, string, combinations, permutation

I currently have the following code to create permutations of the letters in a string. I was wondering what the most efficient way might be to convert it to combinations, where order doesn't matter, instead?

```
public class Permutation {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    permute("ABCD");
}

public static void permute(String full) {
    if (full == null || full.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("You must provide a string of length > 0");
            return;
        }
        permute("",full);
    }

private static void permute(String prefix, String remaining) {
    if (remaining.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < remaining.length(); i++) {
        permute(prefix + remaining.charAt(i),remaining.substring(0, i) + remaining.substring(i + 1, remaining.length()));

    }
}
```

}

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Stream<int []>` of combinations (`int []` is the array with the number of elements to take of every type).

The stream return **all** combinations with **repetition** of **any** size:

```
static Stream<int []> combinationsStream(final int... numElems) {
    final int numCombinations = Arrays.stream(numElems)                 // the number of solutions is
            .map(n -> n + 1)                                            // possibles sizes
            .reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);                                // product

    final int[] queue = Arrays.stream(numElems).map(i -> -1).toArray(); // for every item take n elements
    final int[] i = new int[]{0};                                       // volatile (final) integer
    final Function<int [], int []> next = o -> {                        // compute the next combination
        while (true) {
            if (i[0] == numElems.length) {                              // if is the last position
                i[0] -= 1;                                              // we will back
                return queue;                                           // but it's a combination
            }
            queue[i[0]] += 1;                                           // take one more of i[0]-th element
            if (queue[i[0]] > numElems[i[0]])                           // if no more of this
                queue[i[0]--] = -1;                                     // reset and go back
            else
                i[0] += 1;                                              // if not, go forward
        }
    };
    return Stream.iterate(null, next::apply)                            // iterate getting next over and over
            .skip(1)                                                    // avoid the seed (null)
            .limit(numCombinations);                                    // limit the stream to combs number
}
```

for example, combinations of 3 apples and 2 oranges are:

```
combinationsStream(3, 2)
    .forEach((int[] xs) -> System.out.println(Arrays.stream(xs).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(joining(", "))));
```

with output

```
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
1, 0
1, 1
1, 2
2, 0
2, 1
2, 2
3, 0
3, 1
3, 2
```

of course you can filter any restriction, **without repetition**

```
combinationsStream(3, 2)
    .filter(xs -> Arrays.stream(xs).allMatch(x -> x < 2))
    ...
```

with output

```
0, 0
0, 1
1, 0
1, 1
```

or with min 3 elements and max 4 elements

```
combinationsStream(3, 2)
    .filter(xs -> { int sz = Arrays.stream(xs).sum(); return 3 <= sz && sz <= 4; })
    ....
```

with output

```
1, 2
2, 1
2, 2
3, 0
3, 1
```

and so on.

Example:

let you have baskets of fruits

```
static class FruitBasket {
    String fruit;
    int quantity;
    FruitBasket(String fruit, int quantity) {
        this.fruit = fruit;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

and you want to make fruit salad with at least 3 pieces of fruit and no more than 4 and always with at least two different fruits with your available fruits

```
List<FruitBasket> elems = asList(
    new FruitBasket("apples",  5),
    new FruitBasket("oranges", 1),
    new FruitBasket("melons",  2));
```

then

```
combinationsStream(elems.stream()
        .mapToInt(FruitBasket::getQuantity) // quantity of each
        .map(n -> Math.min(2, n))           // max two of each
        .toArray())
    .filter(xs -> { int sz = Arrays.stream(xs).sum(); return 3 <= sz && sz <= 4; })
    .forEach(xs -> System.out.println(
        IntStream.range(0, xs.length).mapToObj(i -> xs[i] + " " + elems.get(i).fruit).collect(joining(", "))));
```

with output

```
0 apples, 1 oranges, 2 melons
1 apples, 0 oranges, 2 melons
1 apples, 1 oranges, 1 melons
1 apples, 1 oranges, 2 melons
2 apples, 0 oranges, 1 melons
2 apples, 0 oranges, 2 melons
2 apples, 1 oranges, 0 melons
2 apples, 1 oranges, 1 melons
```